# I want to use a number that I got using Debug.Log, and use it later in a game over screen to show a score

Tags: unity, c#, 3d

[image: console]

How can I save this number as a variable to use in a game over screen?

This is my code to get the number

```
    public void StopCount () 
{
    Debug.Log(disRun);
}
```

Comment: the variable is already saved in `disRun`. Do you want to access it from a different scene?

Comment: Yes but disRun is always going up and when the thing collides it saves it, just at that point while still going up, hence why I need the number in the Debug Log.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, I just needed to create a new public int called anything,
then put it under the the function as it only happens once
like this:

```
    public void StopCount () 
{
    Debug.Log(disRun);
    endscore = disRun;
}
```

I don't know why I didn't think of this.

Comment: Keep in mind `Debug.Log()` is just used for debugging purpose and not really helpful in a final version.

Comment: Be aware that this isn't really "stopping" the count, it's just saving a snapshot of the count at a particular time.